# Closed form for number of dimension of angular momentum eigenspace

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, quantum-states

I am trying to construct the totally uncorrelated state for a subsystem $i$ given the information that a spin has total angular momentum eigenvalue $s_i$. I therefore write that the state operator should be given by
$$\rho^{(i)} = \frac{1}{?}\sum_{m_i = -s_i,...,s_i} |s_i,m_i\rangle\langle s_i,m_i|$$
but I have no clue what to write for normalization (the $?$). Is there a closed-form I can put there? For half-integer spins it seems like things would be off from the integer-spin case ($2s_i$ vs. $2s_i + 1$)?

Comment: With "totally uncorrelated", do you mean maximally mixed (instead)?

Comment: And why $2s$ in the integer case?

Comment: Oof, it's $2s+1$. This was a silly question. And I also made an error saying "totally uncorrelated" which is not correct and should instead refer to entanglement between subsystems. Ballentine uses "If the particles are taken from unpolarized sources", and of course I should have written maximally-mixed to describe that. My apologies.

Comment: I believe you should edit to resolve your question if you have figured it out since others may come to have the same question as you.

Comment: Hft has provided a nice answer so I will leave that, but noted for next time! @MattHanson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to construct the totally uncorrelated state for a subsystem $i$ given the information that a spin has total angular momentum eigenvalue $s_i$. I therefore write that the state operator should be given by
> $$\rho^{(i)} = \frac{1}{?}\sum_{m_i = -s_i,...,s_i} |s_i,m_i\rangle\langle s_i,m_i|$$
> but I have no clue what to write for normalization (the $?$). Is there a closed-form I can put there? For half-integer spins it seems like things would be off from the integer-spin case ($2s_i$ vs. $2s_i + 1$)?

For either integer or half-integer spin $s$, the number of $m$ values is always $2s+1$. For example, if $s=1/2$ there are $2$ ($=2\times\frac{1}{2}+1$) $m$ values. For example if $s=1$ there are $3$ ($=2\times 1+1$) $m$ values.

Therefore, if you want your $\rho^{(i)}$ to be a density matrix, you need to set your "$?$" equal to $2s_i+1$:
$$
\rho^{(i)} = \frac{1}{2s_i + 1}\sum_{m_i=-s_i}^{s_i}|s_i m_i\rangle\langle s_i m_i|\;.
$$

This follows because you want your coefficients to sum up to 1. In the case you are interested in, your coefficients are all equal and so they must all equal $\frac{1}{2s_i + 1}$.

---

You can check that
$$
Tr(\rho^{(i)}) = \frac{1}{2s_i + 1}\sum_{m'_i,m_i}\delta_{m'_i,m_i} 
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{2s_i+1}\left(\sum_{m_i}1\right) = \frac{2s_i+1}{2s_i+1} = 1
$$